# office-js + Excel: How to access this in context.sync.then?

Tags: excel, office-js

For example, create a react excel sample following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react and modify it to
[modifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMqKq.png).

where `this.color` is a variable inside App and it throws `'this' is null`

Thanks~

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: You need to provide enough code that we can see what "this" should refer to. What do you _think_ it should refer to?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To reproduce my problem, 
1. create a react excel sample following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react 
2. modify the code in App.tsx following this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMqKq.png 
3. click Run again and it will complain 'this' is null.

I thought 'this' should be a valid reference to App however it is null instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figure out my understanding of js is too primitive. 'this' in function(){} is undefined due to strict mode. Changing to () => {} solves the problem.